# Error when using Final keyword in replacing merge tree table

Tags: clickhouse

My replacing merge tree engine has following design:
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(ModifiedOn)
PRIMARY KEY (CompanyId,
OrderDateKey,
InvoiceDateKey)
ORDER BY (CompanyId,
OrderDateKey,
InvoiceDateKey,
AttendanceGuid,
SaleOrderId,
InvoiceId,
ProductId)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192,
allow_nullable_key = 1;

I am getting an error - SQL Error [36] [07000]: Code: 36. DB::Exception: Cannot read out of marks range.: While executing MergeTreeSelect(pool: ReadPoolInOrder, algorithm: InOrder). (BAD_ARGUMENTS) (version 24.2.1.2248 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode(addr=http:20.235.209.193:8123, db=unify)@-115343875

while running a query -
select InvoiceId, SUM(InvoiceNetValue) from unify.ProductWiseDemandSales FINAL
where CompanyId = 11307 and InvoiceDateKey = 20240328
and InvoiceId is not NULL
group by InvoiceId
order by InvoiceId

I was expecting it to work smoothly without any issue.